# file_get_contents working for some .txt files and not others?

Tags: php

I have a script written by a friend that gets all the contents from a directory of .txt files and uploads them into a database alongside some other information.

aka: filename | Contents

Each file's contents - simple text info - is stored in a corresponding database entry.  It's been working very well so far, **but the contents of a new bunch of text files simply aren't being read.**  The filenames are read fine and that info is imported into the database easily. It's just the actual contents.  Old .txt files that I've imported previously still are imported perfectly.

Examples of files are here: 
[Working](http://pintail.eu/php/working.txt) / 
[Not-Working](http://pintail.eu/php/notworking.txt)

**Long story short** - does anyone know why the contents of some .txt files can be read and not others?  Encoding issues possibly, etc? (though they're from the same person and look identical)  I'm losing my mind.

Thanks!

```
$dir = 'text';
//createxml(10);exit;
$time_start = microtime(true);
$files = scandir($dir);
natsort($files);
foreach ($files as $v) {
    if ($v != "." && $v != ".." && $v != "thumbs" && $v != ".DS_Store") {
        //get work done
        $text = file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$v);
        //get volume, page, county
        $ta = explode('.',$v);
        $ma = explode('_',$ta[0]);
        $last = count($ma)-1;
        $volume = '';
        $year = '1999';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $last; ++$i)
        {
            $volume .= $ma[$i].'_';
        }
        $volume = $mysqli->real_escape_string(rtrim($volume,'_'));

        $pagenr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($ma[$last]);
        $ntext  = $mysqli->real_escape_string(getmtext($text));
        $pdf    = 'http://griffiths.****.ie/gv4/thoms/'.$volume.'/'.$volume.'_pg'.str_pad($pagenr, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'.pdf';
        $thumb  = 'http://griffiths.****.ie/gv4/thoms/'.$volume.'/thumbs2/'.$volume.'_'.str_pad($pagenr, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'.jpg';

        //create sql
        $echo[$volume] .= "('','$year','$pagenr','$volume','$ntext','$pdf','$thumb'),";
        $excl[$volume]=true;
    }
}
// check if there is volume already in DB
foreach ($excl as $k => $v) {
    $volumes .= "'$k',";
}
$volumes = rtrim($volumes,',');
$excls ='';

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT volume FROM thoms_copy2 WHERE volume in ($volumes)")) {
    //found volumes already in DB
        while ($r = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
            //we only need the new volumes, so we will ignore the rest
            unset($echo[$r[0]]);
    $result->close();
}

//create mysql string
foreach ($echo as $k => $v) {
    $echot .= $v.',';
}
$echot = rtrim($echot,',');
if ($echot) {// if i have something to insert
    //insert into DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `thoms_copy2` (`id`,`year`,`main_page`, `volume`, `texty`, `pdf`, `thumb`) VALUES $echot";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
        echo "Done.";
        //create the XML file       
        createxml($mysqli->affected_rows);
    } else {
        printf("Error message: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        echo "<br><br>$sql";
    }
} else { echo "Done. Nothing new."; }
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;    
echo "<br>$time";

//functions ===============================================================
function getmtext($str) {
    $text = '';
    $words = str_word_count($str, 1);
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if ($word[0] >= 'A' && $word[0] <= 'Z') 
            if (strlen($word)>1) 
                $text .= $word.' ';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: The code of the php script would be helpful to answer.  The section from where it reads the contents of the file through where it inserts/updates that data to the database.

Answer (score 1):

No, file_get_contents is equal to combination of fopen+fread+fclose, so it provides bytes as a result. If you have a wrong charset, it will not affect that fact, that your file consists from bytes (which will be returned by file_get_contents).
Since you're not a script author, it's difficult to say, where's the problem, but you should be sure, that your files are accessible to your script (i.e. have correct permissions, for example).

Comment: Thanks. The files are definitely accessible, since they're on my local hard drive and I have read/write permissions.

Comment: On which OS you're working? And does only the new bunch of files doesn't work or all (also old files)...?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the problem with reading file? You've mentioned DB-filling, so, may be it's the problem in your application? (and reading from file goes correct? check it with var_dump, if needed)